# How to get distinct rows by column?

Tags: sql

`Products` table sample data:

```
Id | Name       | Color       | Size         |
---|------------|-------------|--------------|
 1 | Shirt A    |        Blue |      M    
 2 | Shirt A    |         Red |      M    
 3 | Shirt A    |        Blue |      L     
 4 | Shirt A    |         Red |      L      
 5 | Shirt B    |       Black |      M    
 6 | Shirt B    |       White |      M    
 7 | Shirt B    |       Black |      L     
 8 | Shirt B    |       White |      L
```

I would like a SQL query to get the distinct products by color as it follows:

```
 Id | Name       | Color       | 
    |------------|-------------|
1/3 | Shirt A    |        Blue |   
2/4 | Shirt A    |         Red |   
5/7 | Shirt B    |       Black |   
5/8 | Shirt B    |       White |
```

I hope to have explained my problem well.

**Update**

Sorry, I forgot to mention that I need the primary keys on the result rows

Comment: this is simply an application of `distinct`.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much in your title

```
Select Distinct Name,Color 
 from YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
Name     Color
Shirt A  Blue
Shirt A  Red
Shirt B  Black
Shirt B  White
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use what is called a `distinct` clause in your query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Name, 
    Color 
FROM my_table
```

Here is a link to the w3schools explanation of distinct https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Answer (score 1):

Try this instruction:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT (YOUR_FIELDS)
  FROM (YOUR_TABLE);
```

Set your fields and your table name.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, color FROM products
```